# How to persist a Typescript Map on a Ionic application

Tags: typescript, ionic2, localforage

So I have some objects within my application with a `Map<number,any[]>` as one of their attributes.
At the moment I am using `localForage` for the persistence and when the Map is saved it stores it well with `ionic serve` using  an android or windows (browser simulated) but not with an ios one.
Also it doesn't work in my android device.

This is a sample of code testing my point:

```
let myMap: Map<number,any[]> = new Map();
myMap.set(1,['banana','pimento']);
console.log(myMap);
localForage.config({});
localForage.setItem("myMap",myMap)
 .then(()=>localForage.getItem("myMap")
  .then(map => console.log(map))
);
```

On android and windows (browser simulated) it shows the map just fine, on ios it doesn't. The difference is that the ios one uses a webSQL database and the others use an indexedDB one.

Do I need to serialize it? Is there a better way to store data which fixes this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found as a solution to my problem to serialize the `Map` object with:

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from( myMap.entries()));
```

and deserialize it afterwards with:

```
new Map<any,any>(JSON.parse(myMapFromStorage));
```